# How I can add transition while switching from light mode to dark mode in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode

```
  var container = document.querySelector(".container")
    var light  = document.getElementById("light");
    var dark  = document.getElementById("dark");


    light.addEventListener('click', lightMode);
    function lightMode(){
        container.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        container.style.color = "black";
        
    }
    dark.addEventListener('click', darkMode);
    function darkMode() {
        container.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        container.style.color = "white";
    }
```

It is my code, please tell me how can I add transition when a user clicks on dark mode.
Now, It is switching very fastly which is not attractive for user and for me also.
Please tell me if you know

I'm Expecting the transition to be added when I switch from dark mode to light mode
It **Should not instantly change it. It must have a transition of 1s ease in**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Where is your HTML and CSS code ? kindly provide it also

Comment: A strong recommendation is to have exactly a single class-name (per theme). This class-name then gets [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)d at the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property of the very element that is supposed to be the theme's root-element (e.g. `document.documentElement` or `document.body`). All the styling then gets provided as css rules which are related to the theme's class-name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<h1>
Hello, how are you?
</h1>
<button id="light" type="button">Light mode</button>
<button id="dark" type="button">Dark mode</button>
</div>

</body>
<script>
var container = document.querySelector(".container")
    var light  = document.getElementById("light");
    var dark  = document.getElementById("dark");


    light.addEventListener('click', lightMode);
    function lightMode(){
        container.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        container.style.color = "black";
        
    }
    dark.addEventListener('click', darkMode);
    function darkMode() {
        container.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        container.style.color = "white";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
transition: background-color 1s ease, color 1s ease;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h1>Hello, how are you</h1>
<button id="light" type="button">Light mode</button>
<button id="dark" type="button">Dark mode</button>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var light = document.getElementById("light");
var dark = document.getElementById("dark");

light.addEventListener('click', lightMode);
function lightMode() {
container.style.backgroundColor = "white";
container.style.color = "black";
}

 dark.addEventListener('click', darkMode);
 function darkMode() {
 container.style.backgroundColor = "black";
 container.style.color = "white";
 }  
 });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The ease timing function is set to 1s at  tag, you can adjust it as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) and toggling classes using JavaScript.

Check code below:

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var light = document.getElementById("light");
var dark = document.getElementById("dark");

light.addEventListener('click', lightMode);
function lightMode() {
    container.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    container.classList.add('light-mode');
}

dark.addEventListener('click', darkMode);
function darkMode() {
    container.classList.remove('light-mode');
    container.classList.add('dark-mode');
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background-color 1s ease, color 1s ease;
}

.dark-mode {
    background-color: #00008b;
    color: #ADD8E6;
}

.light-mode {
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
    color: #00008b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dark Mode Transition</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <button id="light">Light</button>
        <button id="dark">Dark</button>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should now have a smooth transition when switching between light mode and dark mode. Feel free to customize the styles and transition duration according to your preferences.